# How to add optimization function which is a sum of MLinExp in gurobipy

Tags: python, gurobi

I want to maximize the sum of MLinExp objects of gurobi, but I am unable to do so:

```
self._np = self._model.addMVar(14, lb=-np.inf, ub=np.inf, name="np")
```

Now, `self.ptdf_z2h_pl` is a numpy array of size (1724,14) and  `self._ptdf_z2h_pl @ self._np` returns a MlinExpr (1724,). I want to sum these MlinExpr and put it as an objective function.

I tried:

```
sum(self._ptdf_z2h_pl @ self._np)
```

The error is that MlinExpr object is not iterable.

Also tried `(self._ptdf_z2h_pl @ self._np).sum()` which says MLinExpr object has no attribute sum even though https://www.gurobi.com/documentation/current/refman/py_mlex_sum.html says differently.

My last attempt was this:

```
self._sum_overload = self._model.addMVar(1, ub=GRB.INFINITY, lb=0.0, name="overload_sum")
self._model.update()
self._model.addConstr(self._sum_overload == sum(self._ptdf_z2h_pl[i, :] @ self._np for i in range(self._cnecs_no)))
self._model.setObjective(self._sum_overload, GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

it does not return an error but when I wrote constraints to a file I got:

```
overload_sum[0] = 0
```

which is not what it is supposed to be

Here is a minimal reproducible example:

```
import numpy as np
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB
            
# Create a Gurobi model
model = gp.Model()
            
# Define the variables
num_vars = 14
np_vars = model.addMVar(num_vars, lb=-np.inf, ub=np.inf, name="np")
            
# Generate random data for demonstration
num_rows = 1724
ptdf_z2h_pl = np.random.rand(num_rows, num_vars)
# now I don't know how to set as obj function sum of MLinExpr which is what ptdf_z2h_pl @ np_vars returns, I tried for example
    
model.setObjective((ptdf_z2h_pl @ np_vars).sum(), GRB.MAXIMIZE)
```

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).